# 14.04 Not Auto-Mounting External Drives Since Upgrading from 12.04

Tags: usb, mount

I've upgraded from 12.04 to 14.04 via command-line when my system froze, had to do REISUB and dpkg --configure -a to recover from crash after rebooting.

Now everything seems to work except automatically mounting external thumb drives and external hard disk drives. After plugging in said drives, they fail to show up on the left pane and remains unmounted. I can see the device if I run lsusb and fdisk though, so it's possibly to manually mount it but I'd rather resolve why it's not automatically mounting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Disks` utility, select the partition you want to automount and click this [image] button, then `Edit mount options`, turn off auto options then check the `Mount on startup` box and edit mount point as you like.

[image]

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question. The question isn't asking about mounting at start up. It's asking about mounting when plugging in (note "After plugging in said drives" in the question). Also, I want *all* USB thumb drives to auto-mount, just like the did in 13.x. I don't want to have to enable a per-drive setting. Nevertheless, I tried to follow these instructions, and the "Edit Mount Options" menu item is grayed out.

Comment: What is the Disks utility?

Comment: Just type Disk in the Dash(the ubuntu button at top left)