# How to set owner ext4 by mount command?

Tags: mount, hard-drive

I have a hard drive disk with one sector:

```
Disk /dev/sdc: 160.0 GB, 160041885696 bytes
   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1              63   312581807   156290872+  83  Linux
```

I read about ext4 mount options [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/ext4.txt).

I try execute command:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdc1 first/ -o resuid=1000
```

1000 it is uid of my profile, but owner of directory is root.

```
ll first/
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 янв.  30 21:17 ./
drwxr-x---+ 4 root root 4096 янв.  30 21:17 ../
```

Logs, last line:

```
[ 1516.665370] EXT4-fs (sdc1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: resuid=1000
```

Comment: I prefer to manually edit fstab using an example entry. But this shows using Disks: http://askubuntu.com/questions/451503/14-04-not-auto-mounting-external-drives-since-upgrading-from-12-04 You may need to chown & chmod to set ownership & permissions: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike e.g. NTFS or FAT ext4 supports Unix style permissions so the UIDs are stored in the file system and can't be changed by mount options.

If your disk is mounted on `first/` use

```
sudo chown 1000 --recursive first/
```

to make UID 1000 the owner of all files and folders on that partition.

By default 5% of a ext4 file system are reserved for `root`. With the `resuid` option you can specify another user instead of root who is allowed to use this 5%. It doesn't affect the ownership of the files on the partition.

Comment: And repeat it after every start Ubuntu?

Comment: No, you need to do it just once, just like the files on your system partition or in your home folder. New files will belong the the users who created them, just as usual.