# My Storage partition's name is shown as a bunch of letters

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I have dual boot Ubuntu with Windows 7, and my storage partition(NTFS)'s name is shown as a bunch of letters, and seems like the path to partition is also weird, which makes it hard to navigate. How should i change this?!

Here are links of printscreen:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Weird names for mount points can be resolved by mounting a drive to a different mount point. This can also be done with [automounting an NTFS partition](http://askubuntu.com/questions/46588/how-to-automount-ntfs-partitions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I usually do in these situations is copy the output from the `mount` command to the `fstab` and change the mount point to something more suitable.

The `mount` command with no options list all mounted partitions.
Copy the line which refers to your `NTFS` partition to your `/etc/fstab` and change the mount point to something like `/mnt/windows_c_drive`, save the file and before you reboot, make sure the changes didn't break anything.

This can be done by unmounting the `NTFS` partition and then `mount -a` to mount every partition in `fstab`. If no errors occur you can safely reboot. If an error occurs and you don't know how to fix it, comment/delete the line you copied, before you search for more help, just to make sure you computer still boots.

Comment: I also suggest using fstab: 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/451503/14-04-not-auto-mounting-external-drives-since-upgrading-from-12-04 and use these parameters: `defaults,nls=utf8,umask=000,uid=1000,windows_names` but if a partition you only use occasionally, better to just label it. Then it mounts with label instead of UUID. You can use Disks, gparted or command line to add labels to partitions.